# AJAX and $_POST field is not passed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

Hello can you guys give a quick tip on what I'm doing wrong here.

I want to pass $_POST['url'] to a php file via ajax.

ajax:

```
<script>
$('#checkUrl').click(function() {
    $('#loader').css("display","block");
    $('#form').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'example.php',
            data: {url:'<?php echo $_POST['url']; ?>'},
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#loader').css("display","none");
                $('#reponse').replaceWith(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Form

```
<form id="form" method="post">
    <input type="search" size="35" id="url" name="url" placeholder="www.myblogurl.com" class="btn btn-mod btn-gray btn-medium btn-round" />
    <span class="hidden-xs">&nbsp;</span>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="checkUrl" class="btn btn-mod btn-medium btn-round mb-xs-10">                                  
</form>
```

I know I'm calling the php file, as I can var_dump random text from it. But var_dump($_POST); is empty.

```
array(1) { ["url"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Comment: try var url = '<?php echo $_POST['url']; ?>'; alert(url);  before ajax  and see what you will get

Comment: check for errors with error reporting and check your console.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to emit the value to the JavaScript *before it's even been posted*.  Is all of this code on the same page?  When do you actually post the value?  A form can't show you a value that hasn't been posted yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
data: {url:$('#url').val()},
```

rather then echoing php variable you can get url using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

your code should be

```
<script>
//$('#checkUrl').click(function() { // no need to use click event here  enough to use submit for form
    $('#form').submit(function (e) {
        $('#loader').css("display","block");
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'example.php',
            data: {url:$(this).find('#url').val()}, // while ID must be unique  you can use $('#url').val(); directly
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#loader').css("display","none");
                $('#reponse').replaceWith(data);
            }
        });
    });
//});
</script>
```

and in php

```
<?php
   echo $_POST['url'];
 ?>
```

Comment: `echo $_POST['url'];` => `if(!empty($_POST['url'])){...}` ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- you are right and I know I can use if(isset($_POST['url'])) as well but this is a basic example .. if everything goes well .. he can use if , match , test , replace whatever he want .. thanks anyway :)